# Python: Zipping a Folder + File

Tags: python, compression, zip

I have a folder structure like this: C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\mySoftware\files\output\

In the output folder, there is a file and a folder with another file in.

I need Python to compress the files (and the folder) inside the 'output' folder.

I tried the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, zipfile

simonsFiles = 'C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\mySoftware\files\output\\'

simonsZip = zipfile.ZipFile("myzipfile.zip", "w")
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(simonsFiles):
    simonsZip.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        simonsZip.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
simonsZip.close()
```

But Python creates a zip folder in with the entire structure:

Users\Simon\Desktop\mySoftware\files\output\

and when I get to output, it has the folder and the file that I wanted to compress to zip.

How can I make Python compress the folder and the file into a zip rather than the entire directory structure?

Comment: I guess, files variable includes all the files and folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to provide the second, optional, parameter `arcname` to `zf.write()` (http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.write).
The following function works for me:

```
def zip_dir(zipname, dir_to_zip):
    dir_to_zip_len = len(dir_to_zip.rstrip(os.sep)) + 1
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipname, mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
        for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(dir_to_zip):
            for filename in files:
                path = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
                entry = path[dir_to_zip_len:]
                zf.write(path, entry)
```

This function does not archive empty subdirectories, for this to work you would have to iterate over files+subdirs in the second for loop.

Comment: Just tried to run it by calling the function using: 'zip_dir(zip, pathname)' where pathname was the string of the path. I got the following error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zip.py", line 23, in <module>
    zip_dir('file', spiesFiles)
  File "zip.py", line 15, in zip_dir
    spiesFiles = len(dir_to_zip.rstrip(os.sep)) +
NameError: global name 'dir_to_zip' is not defined

Comment: Well, `dir_to_zip` is defined as parameter to this function, you seem to have made a mistake when copying the code.